# How to shared data between instances classes (backend) and Kivy graphical elements (frontend)?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a beginner with Kivy and I'm trying to create gui for a python app.
I have a backend programmed in python, working alone (keyboard as input) and now I want frontend with kivy. I have two questions:
 - How can I run both components (back and front end) at once?
 - How can I share objects of existing classes in my backend to display information in the frontend (kivy)?

classtest.py

```
class Test(object):
  def __init__(self, attr):
    self.attr = attr
```

gui.py

```
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cols = 2
    self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
    self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
    self.add_widget(self.username)
    self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
    self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
    self.add_widget(self.password)
    print self.username.text

class Login(App):

  def build(self):
    Window.borderless = True
    return LoginScreen()
```

main.py

```
import classtest, gui
users = ['user_name1', 'user_name2', 'user_name3']    
gui.Login().run()
for u in users:
  test = classtest.Test(u) # this should update the user text field on the windows login automatically, but how?
```

In example, How can I update an element of the login window when an instance attribute value change?

Thanks many many times!

Answer (score 0):

It won't update because... of a loop :P Kivy for each `App().run()` or a similar "run" command launches a loop and your:

```
for u in users:
    test = classtest.Test(u)
```

is written *after* that loop. So basically it won't even execute while your app is running. Just put `print('something')` into that `for` loop and you'll see.

Example:

```
while True:
    <do something>
<change a variable in that loop>  # == nope
```

Which for you means that you need either:

- write that into `gui.py` file *or*
- set those things right in the classtest.py

The second option also depends *when* you use the class. If outside of the main loop, then you are in the same situation as right now, therefore - use that `Test()` inside of `gui.py`.

You won't be able to use any code after `run()` while the app is running. Maybe with some dirty trick, but that will bring you only troubles. The code you wrote could be used in some "cleaning", which you can also do in `App.on_stop` method(inside main loop).